# Bash Script Nested loop error

Tags: bash

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
while [ $(cat ~/Genel/$(ls -t1 ~/Genel | head -n1)) != $(cat ~/Genel/$(ls -t1 ~/Genel | head -n1)) ]
$(cat ~/Genel/$(ls -t1 ~/Genel | head -n1)) > /tmp/cmdb;obexftp -b $1 -B 6 -p /tmp/cmdb
done
done
```

This code give me this error:

> btcmdserver: 6: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")

Comment: McAfee Web Gateway do not allow me to read your code :-(
 Please could you post in stackoverflow.com the relevant portion of your code?

Comment: Did part of your script not make it? I don't see the terminating `]` for your 2nd while, or the 2nd `do`.

Comment: The lines that end with `$` look incomplete. Can you post the whole script? Also parsing the results of `ls` is a script is notoriously fragile.

Answer (score 5):

Your second while loop is missing a do keyword.

Looks like you didn't close your while condition ( the [ has no matching ]), and that your loop has no body.

Comment: You still don't have a body for the second while loop. I'm expecting to see: WHILE [CONDITION] DO WHILE [ condition ] **DO [body]** DONE DONE. The bold part is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare whole files like that.  Anyway, you seem to be comparing a file to itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  newest=~/Gene1/$(ls -t1 ~/Gene1 | head -n 1)
  while ! cmp "$newest" "$newest" # huh? you are comparing a file to itself
  do
    # huh? do you mean this:
    cat "$newest" > /tmp/cmdb
    obexftp -b $1 -B 6 -p /tmp/cmdb
  done
done
```

This has the most troubling syntax errors and antipatterns fixed, but is virtually guaranteed to not do anything useful.  Hope it's still enough to get you a little bit closer to your goal.  (Stating it in the question might help, too.)

**Edit:** If you are attempting to copy the newest file every time a new file appears in the directory you are watching, try this.  There's still a race condition; if multiple new files appear while you are copying, you will miss all but one of them.

```
#!/bin/sh
genedir=$HOME/Gene1
previous=randomvalue_wehavenobananas
while true; do
  newest=$(ls -t1 "$genedir" | head -n 1)
  case $newest in
    $previous) ;;   # perhaps you should add a sleep here
    *) obexftp -b $1 -B 6 -p "$genedir"/"$newest"
       previous="$newest" ;;
  esac
done
```

(I changed the shebang to /bin/sh mainly to show that this no longer contains any bashisms.  The main change was to use `${HOME}` instead of `~`.)

A more robust approach would be to find all the files which have appeared since the previous time you copied, and copy them over.  Then you could run this a little less aggressively (say, once per 5 minutes maybe, instead of the spin lock you have here, with no `sleep` at all between iterations). You could use a sentinel file in the watch directory to keep track of when you last copied some files, or just run a `for` loop over the `ls -t1` output until you see a file you have seen before.  (Note the comment about the lack of robustness with parsing `ls` output, though.)

Comment: For finding the newest file, please see [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).